# What all information we can deduce merely from the updated IndexVersion and Generation numbers on Solr admin's core page?

Tags: solr, commit

I noticed whenever we commit some data to Solr, generation number increments by 1 and indexVersion changes to some other number (greater than earlier number but not sure how its count increases).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to tell much except for the fact that some new data has been committed and is now visible.

The numbers themselves are internal implementation and have no external additional significance.

Comment: Suppose I have noted down the generation number and added 40 documents (new or update existing) to index and once the indexing completes the generation count doesn't increase by 40. I think it would mean something has gone wrong.

Comment: Generation count is not a number of documents. But it should increase by at least 1 (commit).